# CONVER RIGHT SQL TO HQL

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have a working SQL query.

But I am unable to convert the same into HQL

```
SELECT * FROM Customer e where RIGHT(e.mobile,10)='999999999';
```

How to write this into HQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RIGHT(str, len)` is the same thing as `SUBSTRING(str, LENGTH(str) - len + 1)`

Comment: what if the where clause column has NULL value ? Will it handle that ?

Comment: When `e.mobile IS NULL` then your predicate will never be true, so there's no need to handle this differently.

Answer (score 1):

HQL supports `LIKE`, so you can express this as:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer e
WHERE e.mobile LIKE '%999999999';
```

Comment: But like query  is not efficient  compared to equal to

Comment: @MuddassirRahman . . . .They should have pretty comparable performance in this case.  Under some circumstances, `like` can actually be *faster*.  You have functions operating on the column, so indexes cannot be used.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-like-predicate